# Passing variables across forms

Tags: delphi

So I am trying to pass a variable (iCode) to another form, but I can't seem to find the issue to why it is not working.

here is a example of the code

FORM 1:

```
  public
    iCode : integer;
  end;

var
  DisplayCodeForm: TDisplayCodeForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses VerifyFormUnit;

procedure TDisplayCodeForm.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VerifyForm.ShowModal;
end;

// =============================Generation of Code=============================//

procedure TDisplayCodeForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  iCode := Random(1000000);
  edtDisplayCode.Text := IntToStr(iCode);
end;

end.
```

FORM 2:

```
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  VerifyForm: TVerifyForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses CAPTCHAFormUnit, LoginFormUnit, OTPDisplayFormUnit;

// ================================Functionality=================================//

procedure TVerifyForm.btnOTPClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(iCode));
end;

end.
```

As you can see I refrence both units in the 'uses' section

(The units I am referring too is the 'OTPDisplayFormUnit' and 'VerifyFormUnit')

The error in Form2 is under the variable 'iCode' meaning it doesn't recognize that variable from the other form

Comment: `iCode` is not a global variable, but a member of the `TDisplayCodeForm` class. To use it, you must specify the object instance you want. (As a comparison, the speed of light is a universal constant, but (a person's) age is a property of each human being. So it makes sense to talk about "speed of light" without specifying any person, but you cannot talk about the "age" without specifying the person.) I guess you only have one instance of your `TDisplayCodeForm` class, though, and that it is pointed to by your `DisplayCodeForm` variable. If so, you can write `DisplayCodeForm.iCode`.

Answer (score 0):

use properties in both form and assign values to this  property,
sample code goes like this

```
    TForm1 = Class (Form)
    private 
      FIcode : Integer ; 
      ....
    public 
       ....
    ///  send data  to any class  via  property syntax, as good coding 
    ///  style, do this in any programming language like JAVA, C++  or 
    ///  DELPHI 
    property ICode : Integer  read  FIcode  write  FIcode;
    end;  
    
    ///   in your application
    .....
var
    aForm : TForm1;
    ...
    begin
    ...
    aForm.ICode:=1; 
    ....
    end;
```

even better coding style :  use getter and setter function  instead of direct assign of a value to Form1